# how to ID which indexes need to be created

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.4

**Background**

I am trying to find tables that could do with indexing. Programmers are complaining that certain table queries are pretty slow.

I found this query here on stackoverflow:

```
SELECT   schemaname, relname, seq_scan, seq_tup_read,
           idx_scan, seq_tup_read / seq_scan AS avg
FROM    pg_stat_user_tables
WHERE   seq_scan > 0
ORDER BY seq_tup_read DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

I tried running on my database and sure enough, one of the tables that our programmers are complaining about appears:

```
 schemaname |        relname         | seq_scan | seq_tup_read | idx_scan |  avg
------------+------------------------+----------+--------------+----------+-------
 public     | widgets                |      511 |     22834898 |        3 | 44686
```

Based on what I read, if you have a table that has more seq-scans than idx-scans, this is a good indicator of a table that could use more indexing.

**Problem**

My next remedial question is how do I know which column to index?

I queried to see which indexes currently exist:

```
testdb=# select * from pg_indexes where tablename='widgets';
 schemaname | tablename |   indexname   | tablespace |                            indexdef
------------+-----------+---------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 public     | widgets| widgets_pkey |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX widgets_pkey ON widgets USING btree (id)
(1 row)
```

And this is what the table looks like in general:

```
testdb=# \d widgets
                                    Table "public.widgets"
  Column  |            Type             |                       Modifiers
----------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer                     | not null default nextval('widgets_id_seq'::regclass)
 id_ts    | timestamp without time zone | default now()
 status   | character varying(32)       |
 class    | character varying(16)       |
 from     | character varying(32)       |
 to       | character varying(32)       |
 start_ts | integer                     |
 end_ts   | integer                     |
 elapsed  | integer                     |
Indexes:
    "widgets_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The thing is to create indexes that will best fit your particular use cases. So it is required to know what queries which use this table you are running

Comment: I checked it out and all queries against this table use the 'id' field in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Just id and that's it? No other fields? There are definitely should be other conditions except id

Comment: no.  it's definitely just ID.  but i think the problem might be more hardware related... or RAM.  Because I don't see any smoking guns on the sql side....????

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) to find out which queries are causing the sequential scans.

You have to add it to [`shared_preload_libraries`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SHARED-PRELOAD-LIBRARIES) and restart PostgreSQL. Then you create the `pg_stat_statements` view with

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
```

Then wait until some workload has been collected and query the view. You can filter the statements using your table name (`WHERE query ILIKE '%table_name%'`) and order to get the longest running statements first.

That should show you the queries that cause the sequential scans.